# create survey from code with rating scale

Tags: development, survey

I'm creating a sharepoint survey with VS2012.

I managed to create the survey with several question and here is some sample:

```
            SPWeb web = properties.GetWeb();
            Guid id = web.Lists.Add("survey", "desc", SPListTemplateType.Survey);
            SPList list = web.Lists[id];

            string Question1 = "choose from option";
            StringCollection collection1 = new StringCollection();
            collection1.Add("opt 1");
            collection1.Add("opt 2");
            collection1.Add("opt 3");
            list.Fields.Add(Question1, SPFieldType.Choice, true, false, collection1);
```

My question how can I add a question with type Rating Scale ?

I can't find any sample of doing this, maybe need to use (SPFieldRatingScale)
but can't understand how.

Hope for any help or directions 
TIA

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it like that:

string Question3 = "from scale 1 - 5.";
                StringCollection collection3 = new StringCollection();

```
            list.Fields.Add(Question3, SPFieldType.GridChoice, true, false, collection3);
            SPFieldRatingScale srs = list.Fields[Question3] as SPFieldRatingScale;
            srs.Choices.Add("some text");
            srs.Choices.Add("another text");
            srs.GridTextRangeLow = "low";
            srs.GridTextRangeHigh = "high";
            srs.GridTextRangeAverage = "avg";
            srs.GridStartNumber = 1;
            srs.GridEndNumber = 5;
            srs.GridNAOptionText = "Not relevant";
            srs.Update();
```

and than add it to the survey list

Answer (score 0):

I never do that but in the MSDN there is a guide How to: Create a Custom Field Value Class that could help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms480788.aspx

Comment: I managed to do it like that: